# Why does the DataTableReader lose its data when using MySqlDataAdapter?

Tags: c#, mysql

I have the following method:

```
public DataTableReader Get<T>(string sql, T[] parameters, CommandType commandType = CommandType.Text)
{
    DataTableReader result;
    using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        using (var command = new MySqlCommand())
        {
            command.CommandType = commandType;
            command.CommandText = sql;
            command.Connection = connection;
            if (parameters != null)
            {
                command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
            }
            using (var adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter())
            {
                adapter.SelectCommand = command;
                using (var dataTable = new DataTable())
                {
                    adapter.Fill(dataTable);
                    result = dataTable.CreateDataReader();
                } // result contains data here
            } // result "loses" data here
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

However, when I get to the row that I've commented about losing the data, the DataTableReader is empty. If I put a breakpoint in the row above it (where I've commented that the result contains the data) result does indeed contain the results.

What's going on? It's almost like something is being passed as a reference.

**Edit:** I should probably note that I've got the same code to connect to a SQL Server where any instance of a MySQL specific class above is replaced by `SqlCommand`,`SqlDataAdapter` instead. This all seems to work.

As requested, here is the corresponding method for MSSql:

```
public virtual DataTableReader Get(string sql, SqlParameter[] parameters, CommandType commandType = CommandType.Text)
{
    DataTableReader result;
    using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(_coreConnectionString))
    {
        using (var myCommand = new SqlCommand())
        {
            myCommand.CommandType = commandType;
            myCommand.CommandText = sql;
            myCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;
            if (parameters != null)
            {
                myCommand.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
            }
            using (var myAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand;
                using (var myDataTable = new DataTable())
                {
                    myAdapter.Fill(myDataTable);
                    result = myDataTable.CreateDataReader();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I've updated the top method to return the DataReader a bit sooner:

```
public DataTableReader Get<T>(string sql, T[] parameters, CommandType commandType = CommandType.Text)
{
    using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        using (var command = new MySqlCommand())
        {
            command.CommandType = commandType;
            command.CommandText = sql;
            command.Connection = connection;
            if (parameters != null)
            {
                command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);
            }
            using (var adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter())
            {
                adapter.SelectCommand = command;
                using (var dataTable = new DataTable())
                {
                    adapter.Fill(dataTable);
                    var reader = dataTable.CreateDataReader();
                    return reader;
                }
            }
         }
     }
 }
```

I've left the assignment of the variable on a different line to the return statement so I can verify that `reader` is being filled. However, when it gets returned to the calling method, there's nothing there.

The code that is calling `Get()` is `var dt = _dbHelper.Get(sql, parameters)` and I know that the sql works because before it is returned, there is the data I am expecting in the object.

**More Edits**:I've been doing some more digging as this is really annoying me. Firstly, if I use `var reader = dataTable.Copy().CreateDataReader();` the data is returned. But of course then this creates a new version of the object, so this might cause a memory issue.

Secondly (and this really annoys me) the `Fill()` method that MySqlDataAdapter uses isn't its own implementation. It uses the implementation from `DbDataAdapter` (which both it and `SqlDataAdapter` inherits from). So how come it doesn't work the same?

Comment: Because you're disposing the `DataTable`

Comment: @DanielA.White Using a data adapter to fill a DataTable means you have a local copy of the data. Further access is not dependent on the db connection/command/… used to perform the fill.

Comment: @DanielA.White the connection is opened and closed by the adapter.Fill() method. At the point that I'm creating the the datareader (the line below) the connection has already been closed.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel but I'm already creating the datareader before disposing of the `DataTable`.

Comment: `DataTableReader` doesn't takes the copy of the data. It needs the `DataTable` to be in valid state to work properly. In other words `DataTableReader` holds the reference to the `DataTable` and uses it.

Comment: No way it could work. Post the code you claim that works. I suspect there will be a difference.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel code posted

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
using (var myDataTable = new DataTable())
                {
                    myAdapter.Fill(myDataTable);
                    result = myDataTable.CreateDataReader();
                }
```

with the using you are doing that when the code goes out from the using, the DataTable is disposed and then yo uwill get empty data.

Try declaring the DataTable and closing it at the end. Maybe using a `try/catch/finally` block is a good way to do this, and in the finally you can add the dispose.

I hope this helps

Comment: I am not sure, but maybe the way that Fill method works in MySqlDataAdapter is different from the way it works in SqlDataAdapter. What happend if you call the Fill after CreateDataReader()?

Comment: Also, by that point I've already filled the datatable (which is the standard .NET one) so it shouldn't matter what happens with the adapter at this point, which hasn't been disposed. The `DataTable` and the `DataTableReader` are both standard .NET ones, not MySQL specific.

Comment: If I run the `Fill()` method after `CreateDatareader()`, result is empty because the datatable is empty.

Comment: The Fill method that MySqlDataAdapter uses is the same as the one that SqlDataAdapter uses (see the end of my original question text)